# Update or Insert into postgres table without any primary key

Tags: oracle, postgresql, talend

I have a table which needs to be ingested from  Oracle source to Greenland target using ETL tool talend. The table is huge , hence we want to load the data on daily basis incrementally. The table doesn't have any primary or unique key.

Table has date column, I am able to get both inserted/updated records from last update date but to insert that data, we need a primary key.

Any solution on how to load the data without using a primary key?

Comment: Post data and code.

Comment: I'd not rely on JDBC to do this, instead create a stage table put the increment there, write that 2 statements (delete + insert) and run them inside a transcation. As others mentioned you MUST have a key defined.

Comment: @Balazs Gunics On what basis I can delete records? Can you give an example. As there is no key , i am not sure how I can frame the delete statement

Comment: You need a key. Period. But once you have that a delete + insert can be used instead of delete, update, insert.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define your key in talend in the schema of the component that insert into your target table, like this :

[image]

And you can use this key to update your table, in the advanced settings of the same component, activate the check box `use fields optins` and select your key :

[image]

This is tested and worked fine against Oracle table that does not have primary key, and it should work for you.